# How to compute the derivative of a tensor-product formula?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Recently, I encountered a optimization problem in a paper, which can be expressed as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\min E(\mathbf X)=\mathbf X^{\mathbf T} \mathbf K \mathbf X\\
\text{s.t. } \mathbf A \mathbf X = \mathbf P
\end{cases}
$$

where,

$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf X = [x_0,\cdots,x_{\hat{m}}]^{\mathbf T}\\
\mathbf P = [p_0,\cdots,p_m]^{\mathbf T}\\
\mathbf K=\left(k_{i,j}\right)_{(\hat{m}+1) \times (\hat{m}+1)}\\
\mathbf A=\left(a_{i,j}\right)_{(m+1) \times (\hat{m}+1)}\\
\hat m > m
\end{cases}
$$

That paper applied the **Largrange multipler** to solve $\mathbf X$ when $E(\mathbf X)$ obtains the minimum value. Namely,

[image]

However, I cannot deduce the first row of that formula by myself.

#### My trial

Firstly, let $\mathbf A =[\mathbf a_0,\mathbf a_1,\cdots,\mathbf a_m]^{\mathbf T}$, then

$$\mathbf A \mathbf X = \mathbf P \rightarrow e_i=\mathbf a_i \mathbf X - p_i$$

then the Largrange objective function $F(\mathbf X)$ can be denoted as:

$$
F(\mathbf X) = E(\mathbf X) +v_0e_0+\cdots+v_me_m\\
=E(\mathbf X) +\sum_{i=0}^{m}v_i(\mathbf a_i \mathbf X - p_i)\\
=\mathbf X^{\mathbf T} \mathbf K \mathbf X+\sum_{i=0}^{m}v_i(\mathbf a_i \mathbf X - p_i)
$$

(1)Compute the derivative with respect to the Largrange multiplier $v_i$

$$
\frac {\partial F}{\partial v_i}=\mathbf a_i \mathbf X - p_i = 0\\
\Rightarrow \mathbf A \mathbf X = \mathbf P
$$

(2)But I have no idea about computing the derivative with respect to variable $x_i$

$$
\frac {\partial F}{\partial x_i}=\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[\mathbf X^{\mathbf T} \mathbf K \mathbf X+\sum_{i=0}^{m}v_i(\mathbf a_i \mathbf X - p_i)\right]\\
=\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[\mathbf X^{\mathbf T} \mathbf K \mathbf X+\sum_{i=0}^{m}v_i\mathbf a_i \mathbf X\right]\\
=\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[\mathbf X^{\mathbf T} \mathbf K \mathbf X+\mathbf v^{\mathbf T} \mathbf A \mathbf X\right]\\
$$

Here, $\mathbf v=[v_0,\cdots,v_m]^{\mathbf T}$

Comment: In [index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) we have $X^TKX = K_{ab}x_ax_b$ so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}X^TKX = K_{ab}\frac{\partial x_a}{\partial x_i}x_b + K_{ab}x_a\frac{\partial x_b}{\partial x_i} =  K_{ab}\delta_{ai}x_b + K_{ab}x_a\delta_{bi} = K_{ib} x_b + K_{ai}x_a$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). This can be simplified to $(KX + X^TK)_i$ (i'th component). Similar calculations can be done for the other terms.

Comment: @Winther Does that mean $$\frac {\partial \mathbf X^{\mathbf T}\mathbf K \mathbf X}{\partial \mathbf X} = \mathbf K \mathbf X+\mathbf X^{\mathbf T}\mathbf K$$ where $\mathbf X = [x_0,\cdots,x_\hat{m}]^{\mathbf T}$

Comment: @Winther OK, thanks a bunch:) BTW, I would like to know if $\mathbf X^{\mathbf T} \mathbf K$ equals to $\mathbf K^{\mathbf T}\mathbf X$. If so, I got the answer.

Comment: Wait a miniute, I think I did a small mistake when saying that your expession was ok above ($KX$ is a row-vector while $X^TK$ is a column vector so something is off). It should be $KX + K^TX$ instead.

Comment: @Winther May I ask you to write a answer for this question? Thanks:).

Comment: @Winther [Lofted B-spline surface interpolation by linearly constrained energy minimization](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001044850300040X?np=y) and the screenshot is [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6hSTC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When computing such derivatives it's useful to do it in index notation (with [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)).

We have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[X^TKX] = K_{ab}\frac{\partial x_a}{\partial x_i}x_b + K_{ab}x_a\frac{\partial x_b}{\partial x_i} =  K_{ab}\delta_{ai}x_b + K_{ab}x_a\delta_{bi} = K_{ib} x_b + K_{ai}x_a = [KX + K^TX]_i$$

where $\delta$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). For the second term we have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[v^TAX] = v_a A_{ab}\frac{\partial x_b}{\partial x_i} = v_a A_{ab}\delta_{bi} = v_a A_{ai} = [A^Tv]_i$$

This gives us

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[X^TKX + v^TAX]  = KX + K^TX + A^Tv = 0$$

From the definition of $K$ in the paper your reference ([Eq. 6 here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001044850300040X?np=y)) we have that $K$ is symmetric so $K = K^T$ and it reduces to

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[X^TKX + v^TAX]  = 2KX + A^Tv = 0$$

This is the same formula as you have in the question as the Lagrange multiplier can be redefined $v \to 2v$ without changing the problem (define the Lagrangian as $L = X^TKX + 2v(AX-P)$).